# Laptop won't show anything on display

Tags: laptop, fedora, post

Yesterday I've tried fedora live 15, when I would leave fedora I made a restart, but instead of restart fedora turned off the laptop. I let my laptop in that way until today, but right now when I try to turn on by the power button it shows all LEDs like it was turn on, but the screen stays in black.
Someone can say what happened or what can I do about that?

Comment: A livecd should not have affected your system in any way. I'm tempted to suggest removing the battery and unplugging the power supply, removing the fedora live disk, and booting it up again.

Comment: If you get power and the screen stays black it could be a POST issue.

Answer (score 1):

What operating system do you have?

I suggest taking out the battery, and then pressing and holding the power button for a couple of seconds. Then put the battery back in and boot. Don't forget to take out the cd as well.

I you cannot boot after that, i suggest contacting the vendor of the laptop. 
Oh and what kind of laptop is it?

Comment: I've already tryed that, but nothing happening. The laptop is a compal FL90 and the operating systems installed on it are windows 7 and debian.

Comment: Try connecting an external screen on your laptop. 

It might also be a hardware problem, in which case you should open up the laptop and firstly check if everything is still correctly connected..

Difficult to diagnose, but here's another page about this problem: http://tips4pc.com/articles/computer%20troubleshooting/computer_has_a_black_screen_and.htm